# Console Window not displaying Japanese characters

Tags: command-line

I can't seem to get the Console Window to display these Japanese characters. I can copy/paste from the blender console window into Notepad and it will display the characters properly, but the console window it just shows up as some weird '?' box character.

example characters (from the blender console window I just copy/pasted it): ['全ての親', 'センター', 'センター2', 'グルーブ', 'グルーブ2', '左足ＩＫ', '左つま先ＩＫ', '左足IK親', '右足ＩＫ', '右つま先ＩＫ', '右足IK親', '右足D', '右ひざD', '右足首D', '右足先EX', '左足D', '左ひざD', '左足首D', '左足先EX', '腰キャンセル左', '腰キャンセル右', '両目', '左腕捩1', '左腕捩2', '左腕捩3', '右腕捩1', '右腕捩2', '右腕捩3', '左手捩1', '左手捩2', '左手捩3', '右手捩1', '右手捩2', '右手捩3', '左肩P', '右肩P', '左肩C', '右肩C', '操作中心', '左肩+', '右肩+', '左腕+', '右腕+', '左ひじ+', '右ひじ+', '左手首+', '右手首+', '左親指０', '左人指３', '左中指３', '左薬指３', '左小指３', '右親指０', '右人指３', '右中指３', '右薬指３', '右小指３']

[image: Blender console window not displaying Japanese characters]

Comment: I think it is related to the used font in the console. It is not supporting Japanese characters, whereas Notepad is. Assuming you are running on Windows OS, may I suggest to read this : [UTF-8 characters displayed as question mark in the Powershell of new Windows Terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67070477) ?

Comment: I voted to close this question as off topic because this seems to be a limitation of the windows console font, and not an issue with Blender itself

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos You're right, I would have gone for a comment but an answer can at least show where to switch to Blender's console window. And although this is a limitation of the Windows console, you have to change the font settings coming from Blender, because as mentioned in my answer recent Windows versions can save app-dependent settings for the console.

Comment: Good one, I wasn't aware of that. Reopened

Answer (score 2):

The console window which you can also open with "cmd" in Windows uses a font called "Consolas" nowadays. This font does not support Japanese characters.

Changing the font for the general Windows console does not change the font in Blender. However, Windows now supports app-related properties for the console window.

So you can open Blender's console by *Window* > *Toggle System Console* and on the opening console window right-click the menu bar at the top and choose "Properties", there you can change the font to something else, for example "Courier New" which supports Japanese, and Blender will keep this font when you open it next time.

[image: console font]

Comment: This worked, thank you! I didn't even know that was possible, I've never even assumed I could click on the tiny Blender icon of the console window for a dropdown list of options.   

For anyone who sees this, MS Gothic, MS Mincho, NSimSun and SimSunEXT-B support the Japanese characters.

Comment: @wikid24 Well, the options belong to the Windows console, not Blender.